# How do I trigger a Github action only when the following scenario is true?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to trigger a Github Action workflow that gets triggered when EITHER

1. there's a push to ANY branch EXCEPT master

OR

2. there's a pull request ONLY on master

**Background:**
We have a team of developers who work on their personal forked repos of an upstream repo.
Within their forked repos, they work on their separate branches (that are not master) and periodically merge them to the upstream master by raising pull requests.
Developers are also encouraged to routinely fetch the upstream master and rebase their code on top of it.
Thus, we want the unit tests to get triggered when:

1. developers are pushing their code on their separate branches (that are not master, reason for excluding master is we do not want the unit tests to get triggered when developers fetch and push upstream master to their local master)
2. whenever the developers raise a PR on the master branch of the upstream repo

Here is the actions yaml file I have written to implement the above scenario:

```
name: Test
on: 
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - master
    paths:
      - <folder_with_code_to_test>/**
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - <folder_with_code_to_test>/**
jobs:
  test:
    # test set up follows from here
```

**Expected behaviour:**
Unit test workflow is triggered according to scenario described above

**Actual behaviour**
Unit tests are triggered when developers push the code on their local branches (it is also not triggered during fetch upstream master and push to local master)
However, unit tests are NOT getting triggered when a pull request is raised from an forked feature branch to upstream master.

Is there some way to achieve the expected functionality?

Comment: It may be related to the fork / upstream connection. I recently ran into an issue where I couldn't get the PR datas in my upstream workflow from a PR event opened from a fork repository. Does your workflow work as expected when those actions are performed on the upstream repository? (push to other branch than master or PR to master based on branches from the same repository)

Comment: I have checked this by changing the action workflow and I am able to trigger actions from PR raised from forked repo on the upstream repo. Yes, my workflow also works when performed only on the upstream branch or only on the forked branch.